# translate text of ion select's ok and cancel buttons

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to translate ok and cancel buttons of ionic ion-select to local languages. These two `OK` and `CANCEL` buttons should be translated. 
Can anyone guide me how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate) you can do the following:

```
<ion-select formControlName="myControl" [okText]="'okText' | translate" [cancelText]="'cancelText' | translate"></ion-select>
```

In translation file e.g. en.json

```
{
   "okText": "OK",
   "cancelText": "Cancel"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ion-select multiple="true"  okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
```

I am not sure but you can try this too

```
 <ion-select multiple="true"  okText="ٹھیک ہے" cancelText="خطرہ">
```

Comment: I think this only changes the name of buttons but I need translation.

Comment: did you tried like this ?  <ion-select multiple="true"  okText="ٹھیک ہے" cancelText="خطرہ">

Comment: actually our application is like this if a language changes it should detect translation from translation files available in our project, directly I don't want to translate them

Comment: in that case use a variable like this <ion-select multiple="true"  okText="{{oktext}}" cancelText="{{cancleText}}">

Comment: can you please accept the answer. it seems discussion is gonig beyond your orginal question.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me using ngx-translate doing the following:

**HTML FILE**

```
 <ion-select   cancelText="{{'SELECT.Cancel' | translate:params}}" 
okText="{{'SELECT.ok' | translate:params}}"> 
 </ion-select>
```

**i18n en.josn FILE**

```
{  
 "SELECT": {  
            "ok":"OK",
            "Cancel":"Cancel"
            }, 
 }
```